# average of continous function tends to zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, harmonic-analysis

why is for given $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(B_\varepsilon(x))}\int\limits_{B_\varepsilon(x)}\left|f-\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(B_\varepsilon(x))}\int\limits_{B_\varepsilon(x)}f(y)dy \right|=0$$

Where $B_\varepsilon(x)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ ist the closed ball around $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$.
I tried to use, that $f$ have a supremum on $B_\varepsilon(x)$, but as I have the average of $f$ and not the integral, this seems not to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: epsilon-delta-definition for continous functions. (change the roles of epsilon and delta in standard notation, in your case for every positive delta there is a positive epsilon such that...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
My problem here is, that $\frac{1}{vol (B_\varepsilon (x))}\rightarrow \infty$. I see that $\int\limits_{B_\varepsilon(x)}|...|<\delta$ but not the first term.

Comment: What is the integration variable in the outer integral?

Comment: may call it z, then you have $\int | f(z)- c|dz$

Comment: not my point. it's much easier than the answer below: $\int_{B_{\epsilon}(x)}\left|\cdots\right|<\delta\cdot \mathrm{vol}(B_{\epsilon}(x))$

Answer (score 3):

First note that $f$ is uniformly continuous when restricted to $\bar{B}(x,1)$ since the latter is compact.  Let $\delta >0$.  According to the uniform continuity, we can choose $\kappa >0$ such that 
$$
x,y \in \bar{B}(x,1) \text{ and } \vert x-y \vert < \kappa \Rightarrow \vert f(x)-f(y) \vert < \delta.
$$

Now consider $\epsilon < 1$ and consider $z \in B(x,\epsilon)$.  Then 
$$
f(z) - \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f(y) dy =  \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)}(f(z) - f(y)) dy.
$$

Suppose that $\epsilon < \kappa/2$. Then for any $y,z \in B(x,\epsilon)$ we have
$$
|y-z| \le |y-x| + |z-x| < 2 \epsilon \le \kappa. 
$$
We can then use the uniform continuity to estimate
$$
\left\vert f(z) - \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f(y) dy \right\vert \le  \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)}|f(z) - f(y)| dy \\
< \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} \delta dy =\frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) ) \delta =\delta
$$
for $\epsilon < \kappa/2$.  Thus for $\epsilon < \kappa/2$ we have that 
$$
\frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} \left\vert f(z) - \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f(y) dy \right\vert dz \\ 
< \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)}  \delta = \delta.
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} \left\vert f(z) - \frac{1}{\text{vol}( B(x,\epsilon) )} \int_{B(x,\epsilon)} f(y) dy \right\vert dz  =0.
$$